# Haskell Char and unicode surrogates

Tags: haskell, unicode

I was playing around with strings and discovered that Haskell (correctly) disallows characters above Unicode code point 0x10ffff (ie one gets something like a sequence out of range error if one attempts to use something above this limit).  Out of curiosity, i played around with the Unicode surrogate halves (0xd800 to 0xdfff) - invalid Unicode codepoints, and discovered that they seem to be permitted.  I am curious as to why this is.  Is it simply because being a bounded item means only defining a maximum and a minimum?

Answer (score 2):

Disallowing the surrogate code units would indeed make `Char` a more correct type for Unicode code points. The Report says that Char is "an enumeration whose values represent Unicode characters", so probably this should be considered a GHC bug.

There's no specific notion of "a bounded item", but it would require extra checks in various places (right now `chr` just needs to make one comparison to check if its argument is valid, for instance) and possibly make some things behave more strangely (if people indirectly expect code points to be contiguous).

I don't know that there's an especially good rationale for it, though, or that the trade-off was even considered originally. In Haskell 1.4, `Char` was just a 16-bit type, so it would have been natural to extend it to 17*2^16 values without adding extra checks. This issue is occasionally brought up -- I've brought it up before -- but most people don't seem to worry about it very much. It's probably reasonable to file a GHC bug about it, though, to get a proper discussion going.

Note that `Data.Text` (which uses UTF-16 as its internal representations) [does disallow](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2010/11/29/a-small-matter-of-illegal-characters/) the invalid code units (it has to).

Comment: Yeah, I gathered as much.  What I meant by bounded is that the usage of a Char restricted by being an instance of Bounded and Enum.  I am building a parser with Parsec and I discovered this when I was playing around with restricting anyChar and oneOf (there are a couple of valid unicode codepoints that I want to disallow for the scope of my project).  It's not going to affect me either way because i was using a Text stream to begin with, it was just surprising to find.

Comment: @MikeMenzel Neither `Bounded` nor `Enum` requires their instances to be contiguous.

Comment: There isn't even exactly a meaning to "contiguous" as far as `Bounded` is concerned. It only comes up when you convert to or from `Int`s and see a hole in that representation.